# Installing dependent Github-based packages with pip

Tags: python, git, pip, python-3.5

I have a Python repo on Github with a `setup.py` and `requirements.txt`. Originally, the `setup.py` contained something this:

```
setup(
  ...
  install_requires=[x for x in open("requirements.txt").read().splitlines() if "://" not in x],
  dependency_links=[x for x in open("requirements.txt").read().splitlines() if "://" in x]
)
```

When I did `pip install git+https://github.com/foo/bar.git@branch#egg=foo` for this repo, it correctly installs the `install_requires` dependencies, but ignores the additional Github-based dependencies in `dependency_links`.

After a lot of investigation -- StackOverflow, #python and the docs (FWIW) -- there's a suggestion that `dependency_links` is deprecated and that everything should be put into `install_requires`. So I change my `setup.py` to:

```
setup(
  ...
  install_requires=open("requirements.txt").read().splitlines()
)
```

Now pip complains, whenever it gets to the Github-based dependency -- let's call it `quux` -- that it's expecting a "version spec". I've tried:

- `git+https://github.com/foo/quux.git@branch#egg=quux==0.1.0`
- `git+https://github.com/foo/quux.git@branch#egg=quux#version==0.1.0`
- `git+https://github.com/foo/quux.git@branch#egg=quux&version==0.1.0`

...as well as without any version specified, both with and without the preceding `-e` in my `requirements.txt` and I keep getting this error. I've also tried different formats for the URL scheme, also without any difference.

How do I format my `requirements.txt` and `setup.py` to deal with Git-based dependencies?

Comment: I also tried the deprecated `pip install --process-dependency-links ...` with the original `setup.py`: It made no difference, still not installing the Github-based dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is running `pip install --process-dependency-links ...` with this `setup.py` file:

```
setup(
    ...
    install_requires=[
        'my_lib==0.1.0',
    ],
    dependency_links=[
        'git+ssh://git@github.com/foo/quux.git@branch#egg=my_lib-0.1.0',
    ]
)
```

Note that as you said, `--dependency_links` is deprecated, and it will be removed in a future release of pip. In that case I don't know what the solution would be.